# Prove $\frac{1-z^\lambda}{1-z} < \lambda$ for $z>1$, $\lambda\in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

This is the final part in a proof (by the definition) of the strict convexity of the exponential function, $\text{f}(x)=e^x$. It's easy to see why $\frac{1-z^\lambda}{1-z} < 1$, but proving it for a general lambda seems much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

We have that by [**Bernoulli inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) by $y=z-1$

$$z^\lambda=(1+y)^\lambda < 1+\lambda y$$

then

$$\frac{z^\lambda-1}{z-1}<\frac{\lambda y}{y}=\lambda$$

Comment: Damn, that's good. I admittedly looked up the Bernoulli inequality but didn't think it would be useful, but close to what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I will only utilize the following well-known properties of exponentiation:<sup>1)</sup>

- $\text{(P1)} \ $ If $a > 0$ and $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n \neq 0$, then $a^{m/n} = \sqrt[n]{a^m}$.
- $\text{(P2)} \ $ If $a > 0$, then $s \mapsto a^s$ is continuous in $s \in \mathbb{R}$.
- $\text{(P3)} \ $ If $s > 0$, then $a \mapsto a^s$ is non-decreasing in $a \in (0, \infty)$.
- $\text{(P4)} \ $ If $a > 0$ and $s, r \in \mathbb{R}$, then $(a^r)^s = a^{rs}$.

---

*Proof.* Let $z > 1$ and $\lambda \in (0, 1)$. For any rational $r \in (0, 1)$, write $r = m/n$ for integers $0 < m < n$. Then by the AM-GM inequality,

$$ z^{r}
\stackrel{\text{(P1)}}{=} \sqrt[n]{1^{n-m} \cdot z^m}
\stackrel{\text{(AM-GM)}}{<} \frac{(n-m)\cdot 1 + m \cdot z}{n}
= 1 + r (z - 1) \tag{1} $$

Now we take limits as $r \to \lambda$ along the rationals in $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0, 1)$. Then

$$ z^{\lambda}
\stackrel{\text{(P2)}}{=} \lim_{\substack{r \to \lambda \\ r \in \mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)}} z^{r}
\stackrel{\text{(1)}}{\leq} \lim_{\substack{r \to \lambda \\ r \in \mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)}} (1 + r (z- 1))
= 1 + \lambda(z - 1). \tag{2} $$

Finally<sup>2)</sup>, pick a rational $r \in (\lambda, 1)$ and write $\theta = \lambda / r$. Then $\theta \in (0, 1)$, and so,

$$ z^{\lambda}
\stackrel{\text{(P4)}}{=} (z^{\theta})^{r}
\stackrel{\text{(2),(P3)}}{\leq} (1 + \theta(z-1))^{r}
\stackrel{\text{(1)}}{<} 1 + r\theta (z - 1)
= 1 + \lambda(z - 1). \tag{3} $$

The desired inequality follows by rearranging $\text{(3)}$, and we are done.

---

1) Any sensible definition of exponentiation with positive base should entail these. Also, notice that $\text{(P3)}$–$\text{(P4)}$ can be considered as consequences of $\text{(P1)}$ and $\text{(P2)}$.

2) $\text{(2)}$ itself is not enough to establish OP's inequality. Due to the limits involved, the strictly inequality in $\text{(1)}$ needs not hold under limit, hence we need an extra argument to resort it.

Comment: That's really interesting, many information here! But isn't it a little bit overshoting?

Comment: @gimusi, My objective was to provide a solution which is independent of the definition of real exponent and requires as less background as possible. So, yes, it may be a bit overshooting due to the intended generality. If OP can provide more contexts (such as which definition is used and what are currently known to OP, etc), then it may allow a room for further simplification.

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation! I really appreciate your great work and contribution to the site. Bye

Answer (score 0):

The Bernoulli inequality is cool, but here is a more basic approach.

We want to show $\frac{1-z^\lambda}{1-z} < \lambda$, or $1-z^\lambda>\lambda-\lambda z$ (note that the inequality switches because $1-z<0$), which is the same as $1-\lambda+\lambda z-z^\lambda>0$. Fix $z$ and let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be $f(\lambda)=1-\lambda+\lambda z-z^\lambda$. We see that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0$. $f'(\lambda)=-1+z-z^\lambda\log(z)$. Because $z>1$, $\log(z)>0$. $f'(0)=z-1+\log(z)>0$. Note that $f'(\lambda)$ is strictly monotonically decreasing and $f$ is increasing in a neighborhood of $0$, so if $f(\lambda_0)=0$, then $f(\lambda_0+t)<0$ for all $0<t\leq 1-\lambda_0$. Thus, we cannot have any such $\lambda_0\neq1$ as $f(1)$ would be negative. Thus $f|_{(0,1)}>0$ and the inequality is true.

Comment: Are you sure that this one is "a more basic approach"?

Comment: It is more involved for sure, but it uses nothing more than taking a derivative.

Comment: Bernoulli can be proved by induction!

Answer (score 0):

For $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and $z>1$,$$z^\lambda<z$$
or
$$z^{\lambda-1}<1.$$

Then by integration from $1$ to $z$,

$$\frac{z^\lambda-1}{\lambda}<z-1.$$